# I'm on mains gas and live in England, am I eligible for the domestic RHI?

Tags: heating, water-heating, renewables, uk

The domestic Renewable Heat Incentive is about to launch, in different formats, to different constituent countries of the UK.

It is an incentive to install particular accredited renewable heat technologies, including solar thermal, air source heat pumps, ground source heat pumps, and biomass heaters.

There is a domestic (residential) scheme, and a non-domestic one.

I'm on mains gas and live in England: can I be eligible for the domestic RHI, and what do I need to do to be eligible?

Answer (score 2):

The regulations are still in flux as recently as 23 September 2013, with the [Renewable Heat Payment Plan](http://www.energysavingtrust.org.uk/Generating-energy/Getting-money-back/Renewable-Heat-Premium-Payment-Phase-2) (RHPP) extended to offer one-time grants to households through spring 2014.

The [ofgam website](https://www.ofgem.gov.uk//environmental-programmes/renewable-heat-incentive-rhi) and [RHI website](http://www.rhincentive.co.uk/RHI/regulation/residential/) provide good resources on the latest regarding the RHI domestic programme. The eligibility guidelines are quite long to cover the variety of cases, so they recommend calling the Energy Savings Advice Service, telephone 0300 123 1234, for queries regarding specific households.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it.

- Yes for Solar water heating.
- No for Heat pumps, wood burners etc